# Arrays of structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
typedef struct Student
{
char nume[20],situatie[11];
int grupa,nr_credite;
} S;


void fct()
{ 
int n,i,c;
S st[100];

scanf("%d %d", &n, &c);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%s %d %d", &st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    if (st[i].nr_credite>=n) st[i].situatie="Promovat";
                else st[i].situatie="Nepromovat";
}

int main()
{
fct();
return 0;
}
```

For the given code, this is the error I am getting.

> Error: C:\Users\Rebekah\Downloads\e\main.c|20|error: assignment to expression with array type|

What am I missing here?

Comment: `situatie` is array of `char`. Instead of `st[i].situatie="Promovat"`, use `strcpy` to copy string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
st[i].situatie="Promovat";
```

Array is *not modifiable lvalue*. So you can't do that. Use `strcpy` instead (when you know the size is big enough to hold the copied string).

```
strcpy(st[i].situatie,"Promovat");
```

Also check the return value of `scanf`.

```
if( scanf("%d %d", &n, &c) != 2 ){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also another thing that you did wrong

```
scanf("%s %d %d", &st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);
                 ^^^
```

It will be

```
scanf("%s %d %d", st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);
```

`st[i].name` decays into pointer to `char` but the `&st[i].name` is of type `char(*)[]`. `scanf`'s `%s` format specifier expects `char*`.

Compile the code like this `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`. Try to get rid of all warnings and errors.